# Grease pencil not viewable to Fisheye camera

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

I think this may be a limitation of the grease pencil as it currently works but I live in hope there may be a way to do this.
The issue is that grease pencil objects are simply not visible to fisheye cameras. For normal perspective cameras it is fine.
Attached in an image showing the same scene with different cameras - the blue box is a standard object which shows up, the squiggly lines are a grease pencil object which only shows in the perspective view.
I suspect that work going on to make eevee work with VR may help here.
I am trying to create a storyboard for a dome environment and was hoping to use grease pencil so if anyone knows anything to help it would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Eevee doesn't support fisheye cameras. Make sure you're in cycles.

Comment: This is in cycles. As you can see, in the viewport on the right you can see the grease pencil which is viewed through a normal camera. The one on the left is a fisheye camera which shows the mesh object - the cube but no grease pencil object. These are 2 camera views of the same thing.

Comment: my apologies, I assumed you were using Eevee since you mentioned it in the context of VR.